# VB.NET - 'If Value <>' vs 'If Not Value ='

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement, syntax

I understand that both of the following do the same thing

`If Value <>` and

`If Not Value =`

But I noticed the other developer at my job seems to use

`If Not Value =`

I was wondering if there is any difference in the logic or efficiency between them and if so which one would be the better one to use.

Comment: If you want to find out which horse is faster you race them. If you want to know which code is faster then time them.

Comment: Good point, I thought this, although faster is not always more efficient in my experience. @Enigmativity

Comment: @DJONES - that strikes me as odd.  When in the computer field is faster not more efficient?

Comment: Speed is not the only factor that determines whether something is efficient, another factor would be reliability, but hey what do I know, this is the reason for my question I guess. @dbasnett (in war, horseback would be quicker, but a tank is more efficient)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chose whatever you find more readable in your case. It's not about efficiency but readability.

Avoid double negatives like:

```
Dim isEqual = Not Value <> OtherValue
```

instead use:

```
Dim isEqual = Value = OtherValue
```

So both do the same and are are equally efficient. But the former is more error-prone because it's more difficult to grasp.

Answer (score 2):

If we were twenty years ago, I would have told you to use

```
If Value <>
```

Because the CPU would have done it one operation faster, as it is just comparing the equality flag after doing the maths. Using `If Not Value =` will result in a negation, then a comparison with the equality flag.

But since computers can do over 2 billions of such operation in a second, it doesn't really matters anymore.

Comment: The IL generated for both is the same so there's no reason to think that the machine code would be any different.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I didn't know that actually... Then you're right, no difference at all